# How to Create a Database in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do I create a database or multiple databases in sparkSQL. I am executing the SQL from spark-sql CLI. The query like in hive `create database sample_db` does not work here. I have Hadoop 2.7 and Spark 1.6 installed on my system.

Answer (score 13):

```
spark.sql("create database test")

//fetch metadata data from the catalog. your database name will be listed here
spark.catalog.listDatabases.show(false)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE (DATABASE|SCHEMA) [IF NOT EXISTS] db_name  
    [COMMENT comment_text]  
    [LOCATION path]  
    [WITH DBPROPERTIES (key1=val1, key2=val2, ...)]
```

[Link](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-database.html) for your reference